# 時に[激]{はげ}しく - 時に[切]{せつ}なく

Tags: grammar

There're other things make me confused while enjoying the famous song "Chiisana Koi no Uta - 小さな恋のうた":

> 時に激しく- 時に切なく
>
> sometimes intense(ly), sometimes painful.

Why they finish the sentences with "く"? Regardless of the rhythm or melody, if the role is to connect the sentences, should they use the te-form "〜くて” to do it?

> 時に激しくて- 時に切なくて

Or maybe I guess there's an omitted part after the "く" like:

> 時に激しく(なる)- 時に切なく(なる)( *** )
>
> somtimes (become) intense, sometimes (become) painful

or

> 時に激しく(感じる)- 時に切なく(感じる)( *** )
>
> somtimes (feel) intense, sometimes (feel) painful

if so, when should I use ( *** ) ?
Anyone give help?

Answer (score 1):

The part before 時に激しく時に切なく is いつしか二人互いに響く. You should think いつしか二人互いに響く、時に激しく時に切なく is one sentence. 時に激しく時に切なく modifies 響く, so the adjectives become continuous form. It is inversion.

Comment: 素晴らしい！Thank you very much. Now it makes much sense in both japanese and my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as poetic lines in a song, where the words happened to have been transformed into adverbs.

Just as in the words of a Savage Garden song,

> Truly, Madly, Deeply (do...)

I'm not going to debate the intention of the song writer, but I'd think it's to leave it to open interpretation by the listener... If the words already usually are associated to what follows then you can leave them out, as you can only (feel) intensely, sadly as in your example.